# How to use database table show in listbox when select from listbox can edit in datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server

C# how to use database table show in listbox when select from listbox can edit in datagridview

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.connetionString);
    string sql = @"SELECT * from amd_err;";
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();         
    sda.Fill(dt);

    this.listBox1.DataSource = result;
    this.listBox1.DataSource = dt;       
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "amd_err";
```

Comment: Bind the gridview to the datatble through a bindingsource. Set the bindingsource's filter property when the user clicks a list item

Comment: From [tagging help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): _The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title._ I wasn't vandalising your question, I was simply correcting it so that it conforms to the rules. I recommend reading through [ask] and the related topics to avoid disappointment when using [SO].